# How to add an overlay using Media Encoder Standard

Tags: azure, encoding, azure-media-services

I'm trying to follow this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-custom-mes-presets-with-dotnet/#overlay.

Everytime I run the job the response is: Error : TransientSystem : A transient error has occurred. We apologize for the inconvenience. Please try again.

This is my custom preset (I put also the Sources element at the end from this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34094014/5940469):

```
{
  "Version": 1.0,
  "Codecs": [
    {
      "KeyFrameInterval": "00:00:03",
      "SceneChangeDetection": true,
      "H264Layers": [
        {
          "Profile": "High",
          "Level": "4",
          "Bitrate": 8500,
          "MaxBitrate": 8500,
          "BufferWindow": "00:00:05",
          "Width": 1920,
          "Height": 1080,
          "BFrames": 3,
          "ReferenceFrames": 3,
          "AdaptiveBFrame": true,
          "Type": "H264Layer",
          "FrameRate": "0/1"
        }
      ],
      "Type": "H264Video"
    },
    {
      "Profile": "AACLC",
      "Channels": 2,
      "SamplingRate": 48000,
      "Bitrate": 192,
      "Type": "AACAudio"
    }
  ],
  "Outputs": [
    {
      "FileName": "{Basename}_hi.mp4",
      "Format": {
        "Type": "MP4Format"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Sources": [
    {
      "Streams": [ ],
      "Filters": {
        "VideoOverlay": {
          "Position": {
            "X": 100,
            "Y": 100,
            "Width": 100,
            "Height": 106
          },
          "AudioGainLevel": 0.0,
          "MediaParams": [
            {
              "OverlayLoopCount": 1
            },
            {
              "IsOverlay": true,
              "OverlayLoopCount": 1,
              "InputLoop": true
            }
          ],
          "Source": "logo.jpg",
          "Clip": {
            "Duration": "00:00:05"
          },
          "FadeInDuration": {
            "Duration": "00:00:01"
          },
          "FadeOutDuration": {
            "StartTime": "00:00:03",
            "Duration": "00:00:04"
          }
        }
      },
      "Pad": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Without the Sources element the job complete correctly.

This is the code I use to create the job:

```
var job = context.Jobs.Create("New Job");
var processor = find the processor that has name "Media Encoder Standard"...
var preset = readtextfromjson...
var task = job.Tasks.AddNew("Video with overlay", processor, preset, TaskOptions.None);
task.InputAssets.Add(videoAsset);
task.InputAssets.Add(logoAsset);
task.OutputAssets.AddNew("Output files", AssetCreationOptions.None);
await job.SubmitAsync();
await job.GetExecutionProgressTask(cancellationToken);
```

The logoAsset has assetFile named "logo.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

Use a single Input Asset at this time. Put both the logo and the video into the same asset. Make sure that they video file is set to the Primary file in the Asset.

This is a known issue that we are working on fixing to allow support for separate "logo" Asset.

Comment: Hi Alex,

We've discovered two separate bugs in the overlay component:

1. A code bug that is incorrectly handling the preset settings, causing some encode jobs to fail

2. Incorrect handling of the case where the overlay image is in a separate input asset

Can you share the Job ID of your most recent failure, the data center used, and approx. time the job failed? We can then confirm whether your encodes are hitting issue #1.

Engineering is working on a fix as I write this...

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Hi, below the requested data:
Job Id: nb:jid:UUID:dab03a5d-1500-80c5-bf95-f1e5d714e520
Data center: West UE
Start time: 19/02/2016 15:27:39 (UTC+1)
End Time: 19/02/2016 15:28:00 (UTC+1)

Many thanks!